# Edit on Google Docs without converting

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm integrating my system with Google Drive. Everything is working so far, but one thing. I cannot edit the uploaded Word documents without converting them to Google Docs first.

I've read here it's possible using a Chrome plugin:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139?hl=en

But that's not my goal. I'm storing the file's information on my database and then I just request the proper URL for editing and previewing. Previewing is working fine, but when I try the edit URL it says the file does not exist. If I convert the file (using Google Drive's interface) and pass the new ID it works. I don't want to convert the user's documents to Google Drive because they still use Word as their main editing software.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is how I'm doing right now:

```
public static File UploadFile(FileInfo fileInfo, Stream stream, string googleAccount)
{
    var mimetype = GetValidMimetype(fileInfo.MimeType);
    var parentFolder = GetParentFolder(fileInfo);
    var file = new File { Title = fileInfo.Title, MimeType = mimetype, Parents = parentFolder };
    var uploadRequest = _service.Files.Insert(file, stream, mimetype);

    uploadRequest.Upload();
    file = uploadRequest.ResponseBody;

    ShareFileWith(file.Id, googleAccount);

    return file;
}
```

This is the URL for editing (where `{0}` is the file ID):

`https://docs.google.com/document/d/{0}/edit?usp=drivesdk`

I know that in order to convert the file I just need to:

`uploadRequest.Convert = true;`

But again, that's not what I want. Is it possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just an update. `Convert = true` should've worked but it's not. I've raised an issue for that here https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/712

Bottomline, it only works if I open the file on Google Docs and then use its Id...

Comment: From what I know, I don't think is possible to use Google to edit Word files, as you have mentioned, is that the file needs to be converted in Google Docs before user can edit the file. As you mentioned, you can install a Google extension to edit files using Office Compatibility Mode (OCM).

Comment: @Andres Thank you, but as I said that's not my goal. That won't solve my problem. Right now I need it at least converting from docx to google docs. Thanks.

Comment: @eestein what client version are you using, I would assume `v3`?

Comment: @zaggler actually v2. What I did for now was to use ASPOSE to convert the document to doc and then upload to GDrive... but as you might wonder that's not the perfect solution... it's a lot of extra work on my server. Not to mention the cost (ASPOSE is expensive)