# Google Drive Files API Convert not working?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

I'm trying to upload and convert files automatically on-the-go. My original goal, as stated here [Edit on Google Docs without converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224183/edit-on-google-docs-without-converting) was not converting at all, but until I can find a solution to that (if any) I'm trying to convert the files... 
And apparently it's not working. This is the code:

```
var uploadRequest = _service.Files.Insert(file, stream, mimetype);
uploadRequest.Convert = true; 
uploadRequest.Upload();
```

Data sent:

```
ContentType: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Convert: true
```

Still, the file is not converted. It is still loaded as a Word document and when I try to open it on Google Docs, then Google converts it:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!